# react native textInput; trigger event when "Done" is pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using textInput to get a users age so on iOS I have the numeric keyboard and the return key type set to "done" so I am using

```
returnKeyType={'done'}
keyboardType="numeric"
```

As of right now i am just trying to figure out how to do something when the user hits the "Done" button.

this is my current text input field

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Age (Yr)"
    style={AuthScreenStyles.Input}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    returnKeyType={'done'}
    keyboardType="numeric"
    ref={register({ name: 'age_year' }, { required: true })}
    onChangeText={(text) => setValue('age_year', text, true)}
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
        console.log('The button has been pressed');
    }}
/>
```

I am yet to get this console.log() to fire. Anyone know how to capture when the done button is pressed? onSubmitEditing() is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the past I remember it won't work with "**multiline={true}**"

I put an alert to test, and used the event itself to get the text. Should work :)

An example in expo : https://snack.expo.io/VPv8Axz4B

```
    <TextInput
    placeholder="Age (Yr)"
    style={AuthScreenStyles.Input}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    returnKeyType={'done'}
    keyboardType="numeric"
    ref={register({ name: 'age_year' }, { required: true })}
    onChangeText={(text) => setValue('age_year', text, true)}
    onSubmitEditing = {(event) => (Alert.alert(event.nativeEvent.text))}
    multiline={false}
/>
```

Comment: still, it does not work with multiline

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more explicit, @MattV's answer is correct, just note, if you use his example you need to also `import {Alert} from 'React Native'`

But if you want to use your own `function` when the `Done` button is pressed, like the screenshot below.

Then you could just add `onSubmitEditing` like this `onSubmitEditing={() => yourFunctionNameHere()}`

```
<TextInput
                  style={styles.textBox}
                  maxLength={5}
                  placeholder="Enter Zip Code"
                  placeholderTextColor={'#6D7376'}
                  autoCompleteType="postal-code"
                  keyboardType="number-pad"
                  returnKeyType="done"
                  onChangeText={text => setZip(text)}
                  onSubmitEditing={() => yourFunctionNameHere()} // <=== here
                />
```

[image: screenshot here]
[image]